# Javascript:What is meaning of sum(2)(3) //returns 5;

Tags: javascript, closures

Here is code blow to return it's value.

```
function sum(a){
  return function(b){
    return a+b;
  }
}
sum(2)(3);
```

It returns 5 but if I type code:

```
function sum(a){
  function add(b){
    return a+b;
  }
return add(b);
}
```

It doesn't return expected value 5. I don't even understand how **sum(2)(3)** calls function. Any explanation for this is very much appreciated.

Comment: Your function returns another function, and you then call that function.

Comment: For further reading, the appropriate search term is "function currying"

Comment: @James Thorpe thank you, this is what I wanted

Comment: This link explains it also:  http://javascript.info/tutorial/closures

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

`sum(a)` returns a function that takes one parameter, `b`, and adds it to `a`.  Think of it like this:

```
   sum(2)(3);

   // Is equivalent to...
   function add(b){
       return 2+b;
   }
   add(3);

   // Which becomes...
   return 2+3; // 5
```

Your second snippet doesn't work because you're trying to reference `b` from the outer function, but only the inner function has any notion of what `b` is.  You want to change this:

```
function sum(a){
  function add(b){
    return a+b;
  }
  return add(b);
}
```

To this:

```
function sum(a){
  function add(b){
    return a+b;
  }
  return add; // Return the function itself, not its return value.
}
```

Which is, of course, equivalent to the first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'sum' function returns another function which returns a+b (2 parameters). Both functions together require two parameters: (a) and (b)
The inner most return, returns a+b. Plugging in your parameters, we get the equation: 2+3.
Which gives you 5.

Please let me know if you have any questions or concerns.